# Clicking "back" in the browser disables my javascript code if I'm using Turbolinks in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Well, as the title says more or less. I'm using the gem Turbolinks in my Rails application and I'm having a bit of a problem with the "browser back"-button. My javascripts works fine until i click back in my browser, then it stops working. If I click a link in my app or reload the page it starts working again.

Ant ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 26):

The [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem doesn't support [Turbolinks 5](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) anymore, so that solution is deprecated right now.

If you'd like to disable turbolinks-caching, just add this meta to your page;

```
<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 24):

Two solutions for Turbolinks Classic:

Set the cache to 0 so that no pages are cached using HTML5 History.

```
Turbolinks.pagesCached(0);
```

Another solution is to listen to "page:restore" event and call your initialization method. This latter solution is more performant.

```
document.addEventListener("page:restore", function() {
  app.init();
});
```

Comment: I've received down votes for this. Has it changed with newer versions?

Comment: Hi, I didn't downvote, but as you can see [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/135) `page:restore` no longer fires on Turbolinks 5. Also, `Turbolinks.pagesCached();` seems to be dead, I think it probably only exists in Turbolinks Classic, not Turbolinks 5...

Comment: neither help now

Comment: That sucks. Should I change my answer? I'm not on a newer version yet.

Comment: @AlexGrande perhaps specify which version of rails (and turbolinks) you are using, and for which this solution actually does work. This way, people will know that this solution is only for that version. I think people down vote because they expect the solution to work in their version of rails.

Comment: Ok I added Turbolinks Classic to the description. We upgraded yesterday to the latest Turbolinks so I'm sure I'll be fully editing my solution since I'll have this problem again!

Answer (score 4):

You can find answer in next [turbolinks issue discussion](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/106).
For me, next solution worked - deleting element initialized by JS (in my case chosen dropdown) using next:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen('destroy');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of completely disabling `turbolinks-caching` in the whole app (making turbolinks integration quite useless) as detailed in some previous answers, you can just disable turbolinks only for the parts of page that are giving you troubles with JS

```
<div id="div_using_JS_functions" data-turbolinks='false'>
 .
 .
 .
</div>
```