# Page isn't reloaded after clicking back button in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, turbolinks

When clicking the back button in my browser, the url is changed but the page content is stale/cached.

I've tried using:

```
def set_no_cache
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

but it doesn't seem to help.

Would be glad for any thoughts/suggestions on how to get this to work properly...

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks/

Comment: yes im using Turbolinks

Comment: Can you try refreshing for me - does this allow the page to refresh?

Comment: when i refreshing page manually after clicking back button all ok

Comment: okay, so it's probably a turbolinks issue. Can you describe what you'r etrying to do with the cache stuff you've posted/

Comment: try this solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029399/clicking-back-in-the-browser-disables-my-javascript-code-if-im-using-turbolin