# Issue with owl carousel items disappearing in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, owl-carousel

I have two pages say ***page1*** and ***page2***. Page1 contains all the items in multiple rows(***see pic1***) and I'm using ***owl carousel*** to add a responsive slider to each row. Page2 contains the details of each item.

***pic1:***

[image: pic1]

***Issue:***

After going to page2 from page1 and coming back to page1, *the items(expect the first) disappears from the row*(***see pic2***). They again appears only when I refresh the page1 again.

***pic2:***

[image: pic2]

I tried to inspect the generated html in the console and I've found that there are ***four extra divs being added by the owl carousel*** which causing the items to disappear. To make sure, I ***deleted those four extra divs in the console and the items appears back***. Below is the generated html in the console

***normal scenario:***

```
<div class="page landing_page">
  <div class="container container-home">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="carousel_title"></h2>
      <div id="owl_demo_action_1" class="carousel_slide owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
      <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 2676px; left: 0px; display: block;">
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 223px;">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="">
        <img src="">
          <div class="caption_bar">
            <p class="movie_title"></p>
            <p class="movie_year"></p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- more items -->
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

***when there is issue:***

```
<div class="page landing_page">
  <div class="container container-home">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="carousel_title"></h2>
      <div id="owl_demo_action_1" class="carousel_slide owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
      <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 3568px; left: 0px; display: block;">
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 223px;">
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
      <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 3568px; left: 0px; display: block; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 223px;">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="">
        <img src="">
        <div class="caption_bar">
          <p class="movie_title"></p>
          <p class="movie_year"></p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Notice the four extra divs in the above snippet.

Below is my code snippet used to display the items with owl carousel

```
<%@first_menu_list_items.sort{|x,y| x["list_order"] <=> y["list_order"] if x["theme"] == "catalog_list"}.each_with_index do |c,index| %>
  <%unless c['catalog_list_items'].blank?%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="carousel_title"><%=c['display_title']%></h2>
    <div id="owl_demo_action_<%=index%>" class="carousel_slide owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <%c["catalog_list_items"].each do |i|%>
      <div class="item">
      <a href="<%=get_item_url(i)%>">
      <img src="<%=i['thumbnails']['l_medium']['url']%>">
      <div class="caption_bar">
        <p class="movie_title"><%=truncate(i['title'],:length => 15)%></p>
        <p class="movie_year"><%= i['release_date'] %></p>
      </div>
      </a>  
      </div>
    <%end%> 
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
  var cnt = "<%=@first_menu_list_items.count%>";
  for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) { 
  var owl = $("#owl_demo_action_"+i);
    owl.owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom : [
    [0, 2],
    [440, 3],
    [768, 4],
    [1366, 5]
    ],
    navigation : true

  });
}
</script>
```

I will be greatly thankful if someone shed some light on this.

Comment: If refreshing works, then it might has something to do with the turbolinks. Try disable turbolinks  tracking on page2 to page1 links. or reconsider your javascript with turbolinks.

Comment: @Yunwei.W The items disappears on navigating to page1 from page2 with browser back button too. I will check your suggestion.

Comment: @Yunwei.W You nailed it! Its because of the turbolinks issue. I removed turbolinks from my app and it worked. Many thanks

Comment: no problem Pavan, but disabling turbolinks may not be the best solution. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029399/clicking-back-in-the-browser-disables-my-javascript-code-if-im-using-turbolin   and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with OwlCarousel2 and Turbolinks5 - on browser 'Back' button click my owl carousel had been disappearing. So, I found solution with these lines of code:

```
    # owl carousel in html.erb
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl">
      <% @trip_route.places_ordered.each do |place| %>
        <div><%= image_tag 'placeholder.png' %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    # application.js
    //on turbolinks:load init owlCarousel
        $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
           $("#owl").owlCarousel();
        }
    //on turbolinks:before-cache destroy it owlCarousel
        $(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function() {
          $("#owl").owlCarousel('destroy');
        });
```

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html