# Rails 6 Turbolink problem on turning back previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am working on a Rails 6 and Bulma carousel extensions, and I have a problem when turning back the page that has js code

My `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`

```
require("turbolinks").start();
window.BulmaCarousel = require('bulma-extensions/bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel');
```

My html

```
<div class="hero-carousel" id="carousel-photo"></div>

<script>
  BulmaCarousel.attach('#carousel-photo', {
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1
  })
</script>
```

If I refresh the browser, or when I visit the page the first time, my `bulma carousel` works normally. However, when I go to other pages, then turning back the page, it goes wrong. How can I attach this piece of JS code on `turbolinks onload`

Answer (score 1):

try `turbolinks:before-cache`

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
  BulmaCarousel.attach('#carousel-photo', {
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   slidesToShow: 1
  })
});


 $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  BulmaCarousel.attach('#carousel-photo', {
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   slidesToShow: 1
  })
});
```

add both to your application.js file instead of adding it in script tag

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work :-| actually it brokes the js part, even the first time I visit the page

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029399/clicking-back-in-the-browser-disables-my-javascript-code-if-im-using-turbolin